# Why cannot bind ‘const char* const’ lvalue to ‘const char* const&&’?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

Constness in

`const char* push(const char * const &&_data);`

means disability to change the referenced stuff. Why I cannot pass `const char*` to a `push`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incomplete.  But given the title of the question, it appears that you're trying to pass an lvalue to a function that requires an rvalue.

It may help your understanding to experiment with functions such as `void f1(const int&)` and `void f2(const int&&)` before involving pointers.

When you know what you're doing, you'll understand how and whether to use `std::move()` in your code.

Comment: Unless you're writing a very specialized library, you shouldn't use std::move(), ever; it is generally implemented as a typecast to an r-value type, so either you already have it and std::move is redundant, or you add extra overhead by typecasting an l-value to an r-value (which forces a copy to temp local), and then the compiler has to create an l-value.  Among others, Herb Sutter noted this common problem in his last C++ book (2014, I think?) when e.g. using std::move for the return types of functions, where the compiler could not move the return value because of std::move.

Comment: move does not add overhead in general; it may specifically inhibit rvo but that's all.